# Redefinition of \- (discretionary hyphen): does not apply to a minipage?

Tags: macros, arrows, minipage, xparse, discretionary

I would like to redefine `\-` (discretionary hyphen) as part of several shortcuts for arrows, like `\-> = \rightarrow` or `\<- = \leftarrow`, especially useful for the often used equivalence arrow `\<==> = \Longleftrightarrow`.

My definitions worked so far without problems. Apparently there is one exception:

Inside a minipage or `\parbox` the macro reverts back to its original definition!

A simple working example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand*{\-}{test}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Normal}
\verb|\-|: \-\\
\verb|\->|: \->\\
\meaning\-  % gives "macro:->test"

\subsection*{Minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\verb|\-|: \-\\
\verb|\->|: \->\\
\meaning\-\\  % gives "macro:->\discretionary {-}{}{}"
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

For the full macros I use xparse to preserve the default functionality of `\-`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
% \- \->, \-->
\let\minushyphen\-
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\-}{t- t>}{\IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
  \ensuremath{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\longrightarrow}{\rightarrow}}%
}{\minushyphen}}
```

Can someone tell me why the definitions changes in a minipage and how to prevent this?

(If it all works stable, I can publish it as a package, if someone is interested...)

Comment: It's wrong to redefine `\-` to begin with.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inside `\parbox`, tabular `p` columns, `minipage` etc, various commands are normalised to a known state, specifically they all run `\@arrayparboxrestore` which by default is

```
\def\@arrayparboxrestore{%
  \let\if@nobreak\iffalse
  \let\if@noskipsec\iffalse
  \let\par\@@par
  \let\-\@dischyph
  \let\'\@acci\let\`\@accii\let\=\@acciii
  \parindent\z@ \parskip\z@skip
  \everypar{}%
  \linewidth\hsize
  \@totalleftmargin\z@
  \leftskip\z@skip \rightskip\z@skip \@rightskip\z@skip
  \parfillskip\@flushglue \lineskip\normallineskip
  \baselineskip\normalbaselineskip
  \sloppy}
```

as you see it does

```
  \let\-\@dischyph
```

which resets `\-` to its saved standard definition. the reason it does this is that `\-` has a special meaning in `tabbing` environment, but if you nest a `\parbox` inside `tabbing` things are supposed to be back to normal.

So you could redefine `\@arrayparboxrestore` not to reset this (or you could give `\@dischyph` your definition in any scope that you define `\-`)

Comment: Redefining `\@dischyph` additionally to `\-` worked, thanks!
Sadly the same problem applies to `\=>`, which is probably much harder to fix.
So in the end, I will simply use `\a->, \a=>, \a<-`  and so on to prevent any conflicts.